# Competing ways to calculate the probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, computational-complexity, continued-fractions

### Background

So let us first familiarise ourselves with the following **trick**:

Let us assume that the problem $P_1$ that there are $4$ red balls and $6$ blue balls in a box. The probability of it being red is

$$ p_1(R) = .4 $$

And the probability of it being blue is:

$$ p_1(B) = .6 $$

Now consider the problem $P_{1+2}$ there is another box and one takes the previous ball from $P_1$ and puts it in this box. This box has $3$ red balls and $4$ blues balls. Now, the probability of it being red is:

$$ p_{1+2}(R) = \frac{3+ .4}{7 +1}$$

and the probability of it being blue is:

$$ p_{1+2}(B) = \frac{4+ .6}{7 +1}$$

Note: the $1$ in the denominator comes from $1=.6 + .4$

Hence, for a problem $P_{1+2+3+\dots+n}$

$$p_{1+ 2 + 3 + \dots + n} (R) = \frac{\text{# of red balls in P(1+2+..+n)} + p_{1+2 +\dots+ n-1}}{\text{# of balls in P(1+2+..+n)} +1 }$$

One can nest this using:

$$p_{1+ 2 + 3 + \dots + n-1} (R) = \frac{\text{# of red balls in P(1+2+..+n-1)} + p_{1+2 +\dots+ n-2}}{\text{# of balls in P(1+2+..+n-1)} +1 }$$

### Question

My question is can one construct a problem $\tilde P$ where the probabilities associated it being red $\tilde p(R) = I $ and the probabilities associated with it being blue are $\tilde p(B) = 1  -I$ where I is an irrational number.

Note: since we are using starting with rational numbers it would take an infinite series to produce an irrational number?

Where $\tilde P$ one construct an expression to reach the probabilities related to  $\tilde P = P_{1+2 + 3 + \dots}$. Does the trick method have a faster rate of convergence (as a measure of the time taken) as opposed methods used by the usual method?

The **usual method** would include any other method which will always work (for example one can merely always guess the probability is $I$ and get the answer right this time) as opposed to a continued fraction (/trick) method? Does this method beat it in the finite case as well? Does one have a method to compute things like $\tilde p(R)^2 = \text{rational fraction}$ and then squareroot it? In which case what happens if the irrational probability is $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: it could be that even with a finite number of balls, the probability of drawing a red ball could be an irrational number ... for example if red balls are slighly smaller than blue balls, the geometry/physics of selecting a ball render that probability irrational ... for instance, if blue balls has radius $r_b = \pi$ and red balls diameter $r_r=1$

Comment: @AaronMontgomery fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

In 1987, the author [C. Badea](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/irrationality-of-certain-infinite-series/F61CA06EF543DADB8F3970EF30D9B5CC) proved the following criterion of irrationality:

For an infinite convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{b_k}{a_k}}$ of positive rational numbers to have an irrational sum, $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$, $k \geq 1$, must be two sequences of positive integers such that...

$$a_{k+1} \gt \frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}a_k^2 - \frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}a_k + 1$$

In your example, you have...

$$P\left[R_n\right] = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}{P\left[R_n\vert E_k\right]P\left[E_k\right]}$$

Where $n$ is the number of urns and the $E_k$s are permutation paths. E.g.,...

$$P\left[R_3\right] = P\left[R_3\vert E_1\right]P\left[E_1\right] + P\left[R_3\vert E_2\right]P\left[E_2\right] + \ldots + P\left[R_3\vert E_4\right]P\left[E_4\right]$$

$$= P[R_3|B_1B_2]P[B_1B_2] + P[R_3|B_1R_2]P[B_1R_2] + \ldots + P[R_3|R_1R_2]P[R_1R_2]$$

This can obviously be reduced to a single integer ratio $\frac{b_k}{a_k}$, i.e., it would be possible to choose marble ratios s.t. the first relation is satisfied when $n$ is taken to approach infinity.

Comment: Any chance of answering this part? "Does the trick method have a faster rate of convergence (as a measure of the time taken) as opposed methods used by the usual method?"

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I searched through Badea's literature and found no discussion wrt the rate of convergence of his infinite series. I can attempt to quantify it but I make no promises that it will be correct. As for the rate of convergence wrt the "usual" method, I don't think the question makes sense in the context of a finite sum. I have only ever calculated the rate of convergence for convergent sequences (which have never been finite). Let me know, if you think I have misunderstood you somehow?

Comment: I think you understand me perfectly :)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous If the "usual" method was used, the sequence would not converge onto an irrational #, it would equal it w/o having to take the limit as n approaches infinity. So asking for a comparison does not make sense to me.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Would you be content if I edit my answer to include an attempt at quantifying the rate of convergence for Badea's series?

Comment: Sure that would be amazing!